# How can I get SQL data values according to machine name filtering?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

When I tried to get specific data values of machine address I could not get values of this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Datade]
    @makineadı varchar,
    @startdate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM HMI.[dbo].Tarihmakine 
    WHERE MakineAdı = @makineadı 
      AND Tarih = @startdate
END
```

And I used this stored procedure inside of this API controller, normally when I tried to get desired date of the SQL data I can pull it but when I tried to string format of machine name I could not get data of this I think this caused of DOUBLE QUOTE but I could not convert it to single ''

```
public class RaporController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Getemprecords(string makineadı, DateTime? startdate)
    {
        HMIEntities1 sd = new HMIEntities1();
        var results = sd.Data(makineadı, startdate).ToList();
        return Ok(results);
    }
}
```

I used this web page to get specific values https://localhost:44355/api/rapor?makineadı=192.168.0.8&&startdate=2021-01-29

Here is my database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Xpz.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What does `sd.Data` do? That's the method that executes the stored procedure and handles the results. If properly written, ie if it uses a parameterized query, there's no need for converrsion or quoting at all

Comment: I think this is only caused of string(varchar) format problem because there will be no error while I am trying to get datas according to DateTime values. sd.Data is a Data means name of the stored procedure which I add to below in first query

Comment: I added my database picture only for trying to get values. Again I said I only have a problem for machine name(MakineAdı) situation.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Otherwise, your parameter will have a default length of ***1*** character!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  If so, *never* use string declarations without a length:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Datade] (
    @makineadı varchar(255),
    @startdate datetime
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select *
    from HMI.[dbo].Tarihmakine
    where MakineAdı = @makineadı and Tarih = @startdate
END;
```

The default date also varies by context -- and these bugs can be very hard to debug.  In your case, the default is `varchar(1)`, which is not what you intend.

The other potential issue is the use of `datetime` for the second argument.  However, what you want is not clear:

- If you. `Tarih` is a `date`, then pass the argument in as a `date`.
- If `Tarih` is a `datetime` and you want the values on the same *date*, then pass in a `date` and use `convert(date, Tarih) = @startdate`.
- Only use the code as is if `Tarih` is a `datetime` (of some sort) and you want the comparison down to a fraction of a second.

Comment: I have no problem for date query, also when I tried to only query according to machine name which is makineadı that can not found for example in database my machine name data is Makine-1 and when I tried to found https://localhost:44355/api/rapor?makineadı=Makine-1, it could not show Makine-1 datas to me as API formation this has formation public class RaporController : ApiController{ public IHttpActionResult Getemprecords(string makineadı) { HMIEntities1 sd = new HMIEntities1();var results = sd.Data(makineadı).ToList();
         return Ok(results);
        }
    }

Comment: I think this is only caused of string(varchar) format problem because there will be no error while I am trying to get datas according to DateTime values

Comment: You can set up a db/sql fiddle of some sort.  I suspect the issue is simply that the machine names do not match.